# Get element from iframe and click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, click, element

I want to get an element from an iFrame and click it. Getting the element succeeded. Unfortunately i cant get the element within the iframe clicked. Anyone with a solution?

Thanks!

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var frame = $('#f314dbebb8'); //ID from the frame
    console.log(frame);
    });
```

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Is the iframe content on the same domain as your code?

Comment: No its not on the same domain

Answer (score 10):

Is this what you are trying with

```
document.getElementById('iframeResult').contentWindow.document.getElementById('buttonId').click()
```

where *iframeResult* is Id of iframe and *buttonId* is Id of element to be clicked ??

Comment: Yeah it is what i try... The only point is that the buttonId doesnt contain an ID but a class

Comment: document.getElementById('google_ads_iframe_/16833175/MainLeaderboard_0').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('rhbutton')[0].click()


this works good for me

Comment: Retrieving an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null

Comment: You can't do this with modern browsers unless the iframe is on the same host as the page it's on, which means you have to serve your directory locally, if you're just looking at html files on your disk, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983786/blocked-a-frame-of-origin-null-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame-chrome

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you are trying to "click it" programmaticly, like via JavaScript?  Or a user interaction like with your mouse and cant?

If you are trying via JavaScript its not going to work.  Look up something called "same origin security".  JavaScript cannot access other pages load via an iframe for security purposes. http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Comment: I know how to use the click function, i gave it a try with a small script and it worked. Now i started to click something in the iframe and that doesnt work.

Comment: Yep, saw your sample code.  Not do-able.  It violates same origin policy, unless you happen to be running the iframe from the same domain.

Comment: Is it possible to get all elements from the iframe, and transform it to clickable?

Comment: it is not allowed to read from another origin.  you wont be able to read anything from the iframe using JS running on your domain.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `document.getElementById('elementid').click();`?

Comment: Tried to make a var from it, and logged it to the console and returned zero