# blocked a frame of origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame - chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm new to Javascript and am learning the basics via a textbook that focuses on its applications in IE 7+ and Firefox 2+. However, I am using Chrome and am getting the following error when running the program given in the book: "blocked a frame of origin 'null' from accessing a cross-origin frame." Can anyone tell me what is causing the error and how I can fix it? The two programs are below.

```
//This is the program being loaded into the browser
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcFactorial(factorialNumber){
    var factorialResult = 1;
    for(;factorialNumber>0;factorialNumber--) factorialResult *= factorialNumber;
    return factorialResult;
}

</script>

</head>

<frameset cols="100%,*">
<frame name="fraCalcFactorial" src="calcfactorial.htm"/>
</frameset>

</html>
```

Below is the src file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function butCalculate_onclick(){
    try{
        if (window.top.calcFactorial == null)
            throw "This page is not loaded within the correct frameset";
        if (document.form1.txtNum1.value == "")
            throw "!Please enter a value before you calculate its factorial";
        if (isNaN(document.form1.txtNum1.value))
            throw "!Please enter a valid number";
        if (document.form1.txtNum1.value < 0)
            throw "!Please enter a positive number";
    }
    catch(exception){
        if (typeof(exception) == "string"){
            if (exception.charAt(0) == "!"){
                alert(exception.substr(1));
                document.form1.txtNum1.focus();
                document.form1.txtNum1.select();
            }
            else alert(exception);
        }
        else alert("The following error occurred: " + exception.message);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="txtNum1" size="3" /> factorial is
    <input type="text" name="txtResult" size="25" /><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Factorial"
        name="butCalculate" onclick="butCalculate_onclick()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this from a local machine, or hosted on a web server?

Comment: By default Chrome will not allow frames loaded from your local hard disk to access each other's content.  If the frames were on the same web server, they could.  Chrome has a command line argument that will temporarily suspend this security check.

Comment: Note this problem occurs with `iframe` as well as `frame`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This happens because Chrome doesn't allow frames from your hard disk to access each others' content. Which, technically we term as Cross-origin request.

Solution of the above problem is: 
1. Either you host your webpage on a local web server. See the following link: 
 [What is a faster alternative to Python's http.server (or SimpleHTTPServer)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-simplehttpserver)

2. Use any other browser like Firefox

Comment: Didn't work for me when i tried after hosting in my local machine.. Got this error: `blocked a frame of origin “http://127.0.0.1:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame - chrome`

Comment: `Firefox 75.0` seems to be having the same problem

Comment: neither worked for me as well even after running from a local server

Comment: @arunwebber Did you try in firefox? Chrome blocks it even with local server

Comment: @amulya349 Yes No luck :(

Comment: @TaouBen it may not be the correct answer now. It was answered and correct 6 years ago. If you have an updated answer, you can add it in this post so that the current members will gain from it. Thanks

Comment: @amulya349 : not the correct answer anymore

Comment: Make sure when you set the iframe to add the following for this to work: `<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="..."></iframe>`

Answer (score 8):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you can install an extension named "Live Server". It helped me when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a local web server as suggested in the accepted answer you can run the browser with `cross domain web security` / `same origin policy` disabled.

For **Chrome**:

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

For **Firefox**:

[Disable cross domain web security in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711924/disable-cross-domain-web-security-in-firefox)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/

[Disable firefox same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 1):

Save the following code as `same_server_source.html`, run `python -m http.server` in the same folder, and browse to http://localhost:8000/same_server_source.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>View same server source</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="/" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-modal"></iframe><br>
    <button onclick="alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML)">View home source</button>
</body>
</html>
```